# Jquery expand and contract sidebar keeping window width dimensions

Tags: jquery

I have a side bar that I always want to have as either a 1/3 window width or 2/3 window width depending if the user clicks on a expand button

I have the sidebar working as the browers expands but I need it to change to two thirds if they click on expand but still keeping the window width dimensions

The problem is that the expand is undefined

Fiddle is here
http://jsfiddle.net/ktcle/jPq9k/5/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

function checkWidth() {

    var $window = $(window);
    var windowsize = $window.width();
    var sideBarWidth = window.innerWidth / 3 * 1;
    var playerWidth = (window.innerWidth-sideBarWidth - 20);

    UpdatePlayerSize();
    UpdateSidebar();

    function UpdatePlayerSize(){
         $("#leftColumn").width(playerWidth);
     }

      function UpdateSidebar(){
         $("#sideBar").width(sideBarWidth);
     }

     function Expand()
    {
        sideBarWidth = window.innerWidth / 3 * 2;
        var sideBar = document.getElementById("sideBar");
        sideBar.style.width = sideBarWidth + "px";

        UpdatePlayerSize();
    }

    function Contract()
    {
        sideBarWidth = window.innerWidth / 3 * 1;
        var sideBar = document.getElementById("sideBar");
        sideBar.style.width = sideBarWidth + "px";

        UpdatePlayerSize();
    }
 };

checkWidth();
$(window).resize(checkWidth);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using nested functions which are not accessible outside of the closure. The easiest fix would be to attach your `Expand` and `Contract` methods to the `window` scope:

http://jsfiddle.net/jPq9k/8/

```
function checkWidth() {

    var $window = $(window);
    var windowsize = $window.width();
    var sideBarWidth = window.innerWidth / 3 * 1;
    var playerWidth = (window.innerWidth-sideBarWidth - 20);

    // ...
    // etc (removed for brevity)
    // ... 

    //Just add these two lines to the end of your checkWidth function:
    window.Expand = Expand;
    window.Contract = Contract;

};
```

Comment: thanks but when you expand the window again the panels after clicking on the expand the columns go back to 1/3 and don't keep the 2/3 dimensions

Comment: You said: 'The problem is that the expand is undefined'. That's the bit this fixes.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following code is working :

```
$('#expand').click(function(){
    $('#leftColumn').css({width: '33%'})
    $('#sideBar').css({width: '66%'})   
})

$('#contract').click(function(){
    $('#leftColumn').css({width: '66%'})
    $('#sideBar').css({width: '33%'})      
})

$('#contract').click()
```

I just get the window width and changed the ratio. I also edited a bit your HTML:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="leftColumn"></div>
    <div id="sideBar">
        <button id="expand">expand</button>
        <button id="contract">contract</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can have a look to the [new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jPq9k/27/).

Comment: What do you mean with "on the fly" ?

Comment: so that it updates as you pull the browser window.  Got it working now though - thank you for your kind help

Comment: Just a quick question on this, if I click expand and then pull the browser window it then converts back the the contracted size, is there a way around this?

Comment: Ok. I understand what you want to do. I edited my answer and now, it's working.

Comment: sorry i think I have been a bit vauge, If you click on the expand button this increases the width of the sidebar to 2/3 but when you pull the browser widow it reverts back to 1/3, I still need to use the  function checkWidth() 

what I need is for is when you click expand it keeps the expanded dimensions of 2/3 whilst still updating according to the browser size